# Clojure - lein run not starting my app

Tags: clojure

When I do `lein run` in the terminal, my app doesn't start up. All I get is

```
me@XPS:~/Clojure/myapp/web$ lein run
INFO  org.eclipse.jetty.util.log: Logging initialized @10745ms
me@XPS:~/Clojure/myapp/web$
```

The app isn't starting and I don't know why

Here is my core.clj

```
(ns myapp.core
  (:require [yada.yada :as yada :refer [resource as-resource]]
            [yada.resources.file-resource :refer [new-directory-resource]]
            [aero.core :refer [read-config]]
            [web.view :as view]
            [web.routes :as routes]
            [clojure.java.io :as io]
            [aero.core :refer [read-config]]
            [com.stuartsierra.component :as component]
            [clojure.java.jdbc :as jdbc]
            [clojure.tools.namespace.repl :refer (refresh)]
            [ring.adapter.jetty :as jetty]
            [environ.core :refer [env]]))

(defrecord Listener [listener]
  component/Lifecycle
  (start [component]
    (assoc component :listener (yada/listener
                                 ["/"
                                  [(view/view-route)
                                   routes/route-handler
                                   ["public/" (new-directory-resource (io/file "target/cljsbuild/public") {})]
                                   [true (as-resource nil)]]]           )))
  (stop [component]
    (when-let [close (-> component :listener :close)]
      (close))
    (assoc component :listener nil)))

(defn new-system []
  (component/system-map
    :listener (map->Listener {})
    ))

(def system nil)

(defn init []
  (alter-var-root #'system
                  (constantly (new-system))))

(defn start []
  (alter-var-root #'system component/start))

(defn stop []
  (alter-var-root #'system
                  (fn [s] (when s (component/stop s)))))

(defn go []
  (init)
  (start))

(defn reset []
  (stop)
  (refresh :after 'web.core/go))

(defn -main
  [& [port]]
  (component/start (new-system)))
```

I can start the app perfectly if I do `lein repl` and `(go)` but it doesn't work when doing `lein run`. I don't even get any other errors so I am even more confused.

Could someone please help. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Your `-main` function is running, and exiting after calling `component/start` because it doesn't block.  From [the component page](https://github.com/stuartsierra/component):

> Note: You will still need to keep the main thread of your application running to prevent the JVM from shutting down. One way is to block the main thread waiting for some signal to shut down; another way is to Thread/join the main thread to one of your components' threads.

Comment: So should I put a promise in at the end (for example `@promise`) that isn't going to be fulfilled to block the main thread? How would I go about doing `Thread/join`?

Comment: Yes, `@(promise)` would work to demonstrate the concept.  However, if your app creates other threads of execution, you could join on these which will block until these are finished.